# jigloo plugin for Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

I've been using the Jigloo plugin (GUI builder) for Eclipse for many years. Now I can't find an updated version that is compatible with Eclipse Luna, and my old version isn't recognized by Luna. Also, cloudgarden.com comes up with a place holder screen, seems that they're not making Jigloo anymore or they're just waiting to work out some Luna kinks.
Does anyone know the status of Jigloo?
In the mean time I'm reverting to Eclipse Kepler, which works for now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I found on the MarketPlace the project page with the update link. 
Here the link: [Eclipse Marketplace - Jigloo SWT/Swing GUI Builder 4.6.6](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jigloo-swtswing-gui-builder#.VGoO1_mG8m4).

It seems to finally support Eclipse Luna (Moon) too. I'm doing the installation right now, let's see if everything works properly.

Please, give it a try too and let me know

Update:

I've tried several times with the update, but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Why are you answering if you don't know if it works?